# Put value on edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I´m doing a currency converter but when i put one value on the editText and click on the botton to convert nothing happen,i've seen the code multipe time but don't see the error, can anyone help me.
I'm begginer in android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


int money1, money2,money3,money4;
int[] money = {money1,money2,money3,money4};
int from;
TextView rate;
Button button1;
EditText ed1; 
EditText ed2; 
EditText ed3;
EditText ed4;
Spinner spinner1;
Spinner spinner2;
Spinner spinner3;
Spinner spinner4;


EditText[] values = {ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4};


 String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN                          FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};
String[] simbol = { "AOA", "ARS", "AMD","AWG","AUD","BYR","BOB","BRL","KHR","CAD","CNY","EUR",
          "INR","JPY","CHF","THB","GBP","USD","VND","LYD"};

 int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
        R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
        R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
        R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
        R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
        R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);





Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) 
        findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));  

Spinner mySpinner1 = (Spinner) 
        findViewById(R.id.spinner2); 
mySpinner1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));  

Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) 
findViewById(R.id.spinner3); 
mySpinner2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));

Spinner mySpinner3 = (Spinner) 
findViewById(R.id.spinner4); 
mySpinner3.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues)); 

 button1.setOnClickListener(this);




  } 

 public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
 { public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) 
 { super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects); } 

 @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) 
 { return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt); }

 @Override 

public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) 
{ return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt); } 

 public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
 View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

  String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN   FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



    int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
    main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

     ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
      left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
     return mySpinner;

     }
     public View getCustomView2(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
      View mySpinner1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

      String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



     int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner1 .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
     main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

     ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner1 .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
       left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
     return mySpinner1;}

      public View getCustomView3(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
      View mySpinner2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

     String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



     int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

     TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner2 .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
     main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

       ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner2 .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
       left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
       return mySpinner2;}

      public View getCustomView4(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
      { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
       View mySpinner3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

       String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



    int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner3 .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
     main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

    ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner3 .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
    left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
    return mySpinner3;}


     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
     }



      void getRate(int from, int to) {
        String currency;
       String currency2;


        currency2 = simbol[from];

        int i;

     for (i=0;i<=3;i=i+1){
        to=money[i];
         currency=simbol[to];



       GetExchangeRate httpRate;  
       httpRate = new GetExchangeRate(currency, currency2);
        Thread thr = new Thread(httpRate);
        thr.start();

       }}}

  private void writeRate(final String text) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
   public void run() {

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=3;i=i+1){
        values[i].setText(text); 

  }
}
   });
    }

   private String readStream(InputStream in) {
     BufferedReader reader = null;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      try {
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     String line = "";
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    }
   }
      catch (IOException e) {
      return e.getMessage();
   }
       finally {
       if (reader != null) {
          try {
         reader.close();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    return e.getMessage();
       }
     }
    }
   return response.toString();
   } 

   private String transform(String rate) {
   String readableRate = null;

   JSONObject json;
    try {
   json = new JSONObject(rate);
   readableRate = " " + json.getDouble("rate");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
     readableRate = e.toString();
    } 
     return readableRate;  
    }


   //**************************************************************************
  //Internal class to call HTTP operation in a separate thread

   private class GetExchangeRate implements Runnable {
     String currency;
   String currency2;

     GetExchangeRate(String toCurrency, String fromCurrency) {
      currency = toCurrency;
        currency2= fromCurrency;

      } 

     @Override
     public void run() {
URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

try {
  url = new URL("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + currency2 + "&to=" + currency);
  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

  int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
  if(responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    String response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    response = transform(response);
    writeRate(response);
  }
  else
    writeRate("Code: " + responseCode);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  writeRate(e.toString());
} 
finally {
  if(urlConnection != null)
    urlConnection.disconnect();

}
}
}


   @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {



    money1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition())); 
money2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()));
money3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition()));
money4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItemPosition()));

int[] money = {money1,money2,money3,money4};
int i;

for(i=0; i<=3;i=i+1)

    if(values[i].getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){

            from=money[i];
            return;}

 }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is - i dont know why its not shoot You null-pointer. I was tied to fill array of text edit's manually like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    values[0]=ed1;
    values[1]=ed2;
    values[2]=ed3;
    values[3]=ed4;
```

Second thing You placed getRate in class of adapter. Its easier to move this to activity class. Move it one bracket farther - so change this:

```
void getRate(int from, int to) {
        String currency;
       String currency2;


        currency2 = simbol[from];

        int i;

     for (i=0;i<=3;i=i+1){
        to=money[i];
         currency=simbol[to];



       GetExchangeRate httpRate;  
       httpRate = new GetExchangeRate(currency, currency2);
        Thread thr = new Thread(httpRate);
        thr.start();

       }}}//behind last of this brackets
```

to this:

```
}
void getRate(int from, int to) {
        String currency;
       String currency2;


        currency2 = simbol[from];

        int i;

     for (i=0;i<=3;i=i+1){
        to=money[i];
         currency=simbol[to];



       GetExchangeRate httpRate;  
       httpRate = new GetExchangeRate(currency, currency2);
        Thread thr = new Thread(httpRate);
        thr.start();

       }}
```

and then You may call getRate in Your onClick listener for example like that:

```
   @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {



    money1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition())); 
money2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()));
money3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition()));
money4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItemPosition()));

int[] money = {money1,money2,money3,money4};
int i;

for(i=0; i<=3;i=i+1)

    if(values[i].getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){

            from=money[i];
            getRate( from,0) ;
            return;
    }

 }
```

Second parameter to getRate is zero, becouse You set it later to values of spinners other than the one in "from" parameter. So second parameter is unused.
I tested that and it "works", but service return 503. I'm really sorry, that i can't invetigate that at this moment.
But i hope it helps with "button problem".
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure because it's not easy to read your code as it is now, but I think you should be calling `getRate` from your button1's on click listener, because currently it is empty.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    // here call getRate with the appropriate arguments
}
```

Comment: how do i call getRate?  @João Sousa